# long polling with ajax/jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, long-polling

I have found a lot of information how long polling works

- Comet tutorial: http://www.screenr.com/SNH
- A thred in stackoverflow: [simple Long polling example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

And more..

So I tried to make one of my own, but I can't get grasp the backend of it, the php part.

**Heres is my html/jquery/ajax:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arduino event poller</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    
    <style type = "text/css" media="screen">
        body{ font:13px/1.5 "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, san-serif; background:#FFF; }
        #main{ width:430px; height: 300px; display:block; padding:10px 0; float: left; overflow: auto;}
        .event { display:block; background: #ececec; width:380px; padding:10px; margin:10px; overflow:hidden; text-align: left; }  
        .event img { display:block; float:left; margin-right:10px; }  
        .event p { font-weight: bold; }
        .event img + p { display:inline; }
        .patient-name { display:inline; color: #999999; font-size: 9px; line-height:inherit; padding-left: 5px; }
        .event-text{ color: #999999; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 5px; }
        .event-timestamp{ color: #000; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 9px;}
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        /* Simple helper to add some divs.*/
        function addevents(patientroom, patientname, eventtyp, timestamp)
        {
            $("#main").append(
                "<div class='event'>"
                "<p>" + patientroom + "</p>"
                "<p class='patient-name'>" + patientname + "</p>"
                "<p class='event-text'>" + eventtyp + "</p>"
                "<p class='event-timestamp'>" + timestamp + "</p>"
                "</div>"
                );
        }
        
        /*This requests the url "getevents.php" When it complete*/
        function waitForEvents()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getevents.php",
                
                async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
                cache: false,
                timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */
                
                success: function(patientroom, patientname, eventtyp, timestamp) /* called when request to getevents.php completes */
                {
                    addevents(patientroom, patientname, eventtyp, timestamp);
                    setTimeout(
                        'waitForEvents()', /* Request next event */
                         1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */                   
                        );
                    },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("Error:" + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                    setTimeout(
                        'waitForEvents()', /* Try again after.. */
                        "15000"); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */        
                },
            });
        };
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
                waitForEvents(); /* Start the inital request */
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the regular "backend" php part that I have written:**

```
<?php
//row loop
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","something","something");
        if(!con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        
        mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY eventID DESC");
        //Start container
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<div class='event'>";
            echo "<img src='img/ev_img/red.jpg' alt='picture' />";
            echo "<p>" . $row['rumNr'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='patient-name'>" . $row['inneboendeNamn'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='event-text'>" . $row['handelse'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='event-timestamp'>" . $row['tid'] . "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        mysql_close($con);
   ?>
```

**Any tips or ideas?
The example doesn't have to be scaleable, secure or complete, it just needs to work!**

Comment: `setTimeout('waitForEvents()'` Passing a string to setTimeout uses `eval`. `eval` is evil. Please pass functions like so: `setTimeout(waitForEvents`

Comment: does it work? not work? have errors? no errors? i see no real question here

Comment: What's not working? Can we have some more information on what you're having a hard time with? Superficially, the concept looks OK.